# Move semantics optimization with if statement

Tags: c++, optimization, move

Consider code

```cpp
std::vector<float> handle(const std::vector<float> &input, const std::size_t parameter){
    if (parameter == 1)
        return std::vector<float>(input);
    std::vector<float> temp(input.size() * parameter);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i) {
        temp[i] = input[i / parameter];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

As far as I understand, `std::move` is superflous in classic situations, but what about condition statements and different possible return statements?
Should I use `std::move` in return statements on the 3d and 8th line?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.

Comment: On the 3rd line you should but can't use `std::move`, you can't move `const` objects.